# JSON inherit properties

Tags: json, libgdx

I have this Json file that describes the style (colors etc...) of some widgets. It defines a default style for each widget, and I could add more styles.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }

},
```

I'd like to add a style that extends the default, so that I don't have to copy all values of the default implementation. Something like `highlighted extends default: {bgColor: green }` so that the 'highlighted' still has the font properties from default.

Is this possible with json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is just the notation part of the equation. JSON is a grammer that helps you to determine legal grammer.

This is a legal JSON:

```
{ "default" : { "font": "default-font", "fontColor": "white" } }
```

So the question of inheritance is a question of the builder that uses the json to setup the properties of your objects based on the string.

Based on what i read in the [libgdx API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/) i do not see a way of doing what you want.
I do not know all intricacies of how the objects are built.

I will read up on that and edit my answer later.

---

EDIT:
My brief search did only reveal [standard serializer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.html) behaviour. So my expectancy would be that your object is created with an empty constructor and afterwards the values from the JSON are written.
If that is the case the behaviour you want is likely not implemented.

Comment: I'm not going to tamper with the builder too much, so would you say that just copying over all properties from `default` into my other objects and just add other properties to it?